# How to setup include Chrome Logger for PHP (previously known as ChromePHP)

Tags: php

I'm just getting started with PHP and writing echo statements to help me debug. I saw on here recommendations for Chrome Logger. I've installed the Chrome extension and I can see it in the upper right corner of the browser. I also downloaded ChromePhp.php and uploaded it to my server in the same directory as my php file I'm trying to debug.

So then in my php at the top of the page I've written `include 'ChromePhp.php';`
Then when I render that page from inside Chrome I expected to see the menu bar as shown on the Chrome Logger website showing *Elements, Resources, Network, ..., Console*, etc.

But instead i'm seeing a page that looks like this attachment and then my code *way* at the bottom. It's as though my include statement isn't working and it's instead just displaying the entire ChromePhp.php file in the browser.

What am I doing wrong?[image]

Comment: Did you ever end up fixing this? I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did 3 mistakes:

1) Chrome Logger extension works in combo with ChromePhp.php for the situation where you run PHP code hosted on a server where you only have FTP access (and cannot change PHP paramenters, nor can debug PHP code on the server).
You didn't mention if that's your case. If you're running a local PHP server on your computer, you don't need the Chrome extension for debugging.

2) Your screenshot shows this GitHub page, not your own PHP page: https://github.com/ccampbell/chromephp/blob/master/ChromePhp.php
That means you should try the Chrome extension on your own PHP website, not on the GitHub website.

3) Once you're on your PHP website, right-click in Chrome and choose Inspect. That will make you see *Elements, Resources, Network, ..., Console*, etc.

Comment: I have the same issue. Your second comment doesn't explain why php is redirecting to the github page. You're right of course, but we have no idea how to fix it. At least I don't :)

Comment: @VincentVancalbergh, sorry for the late reply, but StackOverflow website didn't notify me about your comment. In order to figure out what your PHP code is doing, I'd need of course to see that code.
I can't tell it's redirecting to the ChromePHP GitHub page. I can only tell the screenshot is from ChromePHP GitHub page. How you got there it's you who should provide more info.

Comment: I find it strange any include would redirect to a github page. No matter what my code looks like. Like... Why is it even in there?? When would this be a desirable action? (And about my specific code: The comment section isn't suited for code-sharing and I found my bug without the logger. So we'd better drop that.)

Comment: @VincentVancalbergh fair enough, raising a brand new question about your issue seems the right thing to do.